# Assembler for ToyVM

Tags: java, assembly

After rolling my own [virtual machine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122663/toyvm-a-small-and-simple-virtual-machine-in-c-follow-up), I decided to implement an assembler for it. Ironically, it's all Java, since I needed to do a lot of text manipulations. Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Here is the main component:

**ToyVMAssembler.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.toy.assembler;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class is responsible for assembling a ToyVM source file.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 10, 2016).
 */
public class ToyVMAssembler {

    public static final byte REG1 = 0x00;
    public static final byte REG2 = 0x01;
    public static final byte REG3 = 0x02;
    public static final byte REG4 = 0x03;

    public static final byte ADD = 0x01;
    public static final byte NEG = 0x02;
    public static final byte MUL = 0x03;
    public static final byte DIV = 0x04;
    public static final byte MOD = 0x05;

    public static final byte CMP = 0x10;
    public static final byte JA  = 0x11;
    public static final byte JE  = 0x12;
    public static final byte JB  = 0x13;
    public static final byte JMP = 0x14;

    public static final byte CALL = 0x20;
    public static final byte RET  = 0x21;

    public static final byte LOAD  = 0x30;
    public static final byte STORE = 0x31;
    public static final byte CONST = 0x32;

    public static final byte HALT = 0x40;
    public static final byte INT  = 0x41;
    public static final byte NOP  = 0x42;

    public static final byte PUSH     = 0x50;
    public static final byte PUSH_ALL = 0x51;
    public static final byte POP      = 0x52;
    public static final byte POP_ALL  = 0x53;
    public static final byte LSP      = 0x54;

    /**
     * Specifies the token starting a one-line comment.
     */
    private static final String COMMENT_START_TOKEN = "//";

    private final List<String> sourceCodeLineList;
    private final List<Byte> machineCode = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<Integer, String> mapAddressToLabel = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Integer> mapLabelToAddress = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, InstructionAssembler> mapOpcodeToAssembler 
            = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<String, Integer> mapWordNameToWordValue = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, String> mapStringNameToStringValue 
            = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<String, Integer> mapWordNameToAddress   = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Integer> mapStringNameToAddress = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<Integer, String> mapAddressToWordName = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Integer, String> mapAddressToStringName = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<Integer, String> mapAddressToName = new HashMap<>();

    private final List<String> pendingLabels = new ArrayList<>();
    private final String fileName;
    private int lineNumber = 1;

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface InstructionAssembler {
        void assemble(String line);
    }

    public ToyVMAssembler(String fileName, List<String> sourceCodeLineList) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(sourceCodeLineList,
                               "The input source code line list is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(fileName, "The input file name is null.");

        this.sourceCodeLineList  = sourceCodeLineList;
        this.fileName = fileName;

        buildOpcodeMap();
    }

    private void buildOpcodeMap() {
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("add",   this::assembleAdd    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("neg",   this::assembleNeg    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("mul",   this::assembleMul    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("div",   this::assembleDiv    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("mod",   this::assembleMod    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("cmp",   this::assembleCmp    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("ja",    this::assembleJa     );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("je",    this::assembleJe     );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("jb",    this::assembleJb     );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("jmp",   this::assembleJmp    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("call",  this::assembleCall   );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("ret",   this::assembleRet    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("load",  this::assembleLoad   );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("store", this::assembleStore  );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("const", this::assembleConst  );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("halt",  this::assembleHalt   );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("int",   this::assembleInt    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("nop",   this::assembleNop    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("push",  this::assemblePush   );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("pusha", this::assemblePushAll);
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("pop",   this::assemblePop    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("popa",  this::assemblePopAll );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("lsp",   this::assembleLsp    );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("word",  this::assembleWord   );
        mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("str",   this::assembleString );
    }

    public byte[] assemble() {
        for (String sourceCodeLine : sourceCodeLineList) {
            assembleSourceCodeLine(sourceCodeLine);
            lineNumber++;
        }

        resolveWords();
        resolveStrings();
        resolveLabels(); 
        resolveReferences();
        return convertMachineCodeToByteArray();
    }

    private void resolveWords() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : 
                mapWordNameToWordValue.entrySet()) {
            mapWordNameToAddress.put(entry.getKey(), machineCode.size());
            emitData(entry.getValue());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry :
                mapAddressToWordName.entrySet()) {
            setAddress(entry.getKey(),
                       mapWordNameToAddress.get(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    private void resolveStrings() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :
                mapStringNameToStringValue.entrySet()) {
            mapStringNameToAddress.put(entry.getKey(), machineCode.size());
            emitString(entry.getValue());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry :
                mapAddressToStringName.entrySet()) {
            setAddress(entry.getKey(),
                       mapStringNameToAddress.get(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    // Resolves all symbolical references (labels).
    private void resolveLabels() {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mapAddressToLabel.entrySet()) {
            String label = entry.getValue();

            if (!mapLabelToAddress.containsKey(label)) {
                throw new AssemblyException(
                        "ERROR: Label \"" + label + "\" is not defined.");
            }

            Integer address = mapLabelToAddress.get(label);
            setAddress(entry.getKey(), address);
        }
    }

    private void resolveReferences() {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mapAddressToName.entrySet()) {
            String name = entry.getValue();

            if (mapStringNameToAddress.containsKey(name)) {
                setAddress(entry.getKey(), mapStringNameToAddress.get(name));
            } else if (mapWordNameToAddress.containsKey(name)) {
                setAddress(entry.getKey(), mapWordNameToAddress.get(name));
            } else {
                throw new AssemblyException(
                        errorHeader() +
                        "\"" + name + "\" is not declared.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void assembleSourceCodeLine(String line) {
        // Prune the possible comment.
        line = line.split(COMMENT_START_TOKEN)[0].trim();
        // Deal with the possible label.
        String[] parts = handleLabel(line);
        String actualLine;

        if (parts.length == 1) {
            actualLine = parts[0];
        } else {
            pendingLabels.add(parts[0]);
            actualLine = parts[1];
        }

        if (actualLine.trim().isEmpty()) {
            // Omit empty line.
            return;
        }

        // Resolve all preceding labels.
        pendingLabels.stream().forEach((label) -> {
            mapLabelToAddress.put(label, machineCode.size());
        });

        pendingLabels.clear();

        // Switch to assembing the actual instruction.
        InstructionAssembler instructionAssembler = 
                mapOpcodeToAssembler.get(toTokens(actualLine)[0]);

        if (instructionAssembler == null) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "Unknown instruction \"" + actualLine + "\".");
        }

        instructionAssembler.assemble(actualLine);
    }

    private void emitRegister(String registerToken) {
        switch (registerToken) {
            case "reg1":
                machineCode.add(REG1);
                return;

            case "reg2":
                machineCode.add(REG2);
                return;

            case "reg3":
                machineCode.add(REG3);
                return;

            case "reg4":
                machineCode.add(REG4);
                return;

            default:
                throw new AssemblyException(
                        errorHeader() +
                        "Unknown register token: \"" + registerToken + "\".");
        }
    }

    private void emitAddress(int address) {
        machineCode.add((byte) (address & 0xff));
        machineCode.add((byte)((address >>>= 8) & 0xff));
        machineCode.add((byte)((address >>>= 8) & 0xff));
        machineCode.add((byte)((address >>>= 8) & 0xff));
    }

    private void emitData(int data) {
        emitAddress(data);
    }

    private void emitByte(byte b) {
        machineCode.add(b);
    }

    private void emitString(String string) {
        for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
            // We support only ANSI.
            machineCode.add((byte) c);
        }

        // Zero-terminate the string.
        machineCode.add((byte) 0);
    }

    private void emitOpcode(byte opcode) {
        machineCode.add(opcode);
    }

    private void setAddress(int index, int address) {
        machineCode.set(index, (byte)(address & 0xff));
        machineCode.set(index + 1, (byte)((address >>>= 8) & 0xff));
        machineCode.set(index + 2, (byte)((address >>>= 8) & 0xff));
        machineCode.set(index + 3, (byte)((address >>>= 8) & 0xff));
    }

    private void assembleAdd(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'add' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"add regi regj\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(ADD);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
        emitRegister(tokens[2]);
    }

    private void assembleNeg(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'neg' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"neg regi\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(NEG);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
    }

    private void assembleMul(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'mul' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"mul regi regj\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(MUL);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
        emitRegister(tokens[2]);
    }

    private void assembleDiv(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'div' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"div regi regj\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(DIV);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
        emitRegister(tokens[2]);
    }

    private void assembleMod(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'mod' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"mod regi regj\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(MOD);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
        emitRegister(tokens[2]);
    }

    private void assembleCmp(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'cmp' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"cmp regi regj\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(CMP);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
        emitRegister(tokens[2]);
    }

    private void assembleJa(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'ja' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"ja label\" or \"ja address\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(JA);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(hexStringToInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(toInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToLabel.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[1]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleJe(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'je' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"je label\" or \"je address\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(JE);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(hexStringToInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(toInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToLabel.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[1]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleJb(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'jb' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"jb label\" or \"jb address\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(JB);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(hexStringToInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(toInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToLabel.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[1]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleJmp(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'jmp' instructoin requires exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"jmp label\" or \"jmp address\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(JMP);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(hexStringToInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(toInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToLabel.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[1]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleCall(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'call' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"call label\" or \"call address\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(CALL);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(hexStringToInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitAddress(toInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToLabel.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[1]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleRet(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 1) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'ret' instruction must not have any arguments.");
        }

        emitOpcode(RET);
    }

    private void assembleLoad(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'load' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"load regi address\" or \"load regi label\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(LOAD);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[2])) {
            emitAddress(hexStringToInteger(tokens[2]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[2])) {
            emitAddress(toInteger(tokens[2]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToName.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[2]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleStore(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'store' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"store regi address\" or \"store regi label\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(STORE);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[2])) {
            emitAddress(hexStringToInteger(tokens[2]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[2])) {
            emitAddress(toInteger(tokens[2]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToName.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[2]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleConst(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'const' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"cosnt regi constant\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(CONST);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[2])) {
            emitData(hexStringToInteger(tokens[2]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[2])) {
            emitData(toInteger(tokens[2]));
        } else {
            mapAddressToName.put(machineCode.size(), tokens[2]);
            emitAddress(0);
        }
    }

    private void assembleHalt(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 1) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'halt' instruction must not have any arguments.");
        }

        emitOpcode(HALT);
    }

    private void assembleInt(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'int' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"int interrupt_number\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(INT);

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitByte((byte) hexStringToInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[1])) {
            emitByte((byte) toInteger(tokens[1]));
        } else {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    "The interrupt number is not a valid decimal or " +
                    "hexadecimal integer: \"" + tokens[1] + "\".");
        }
    }

    private void assembleNop(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 1) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'nop' instruction must not have arguments.");
        }

        emitOpcode(NOP);
    }

    private void assemblePush(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'push' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " + 
                    "\"push regi\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(PUSH);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
    }

    private void assemblePushAll(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 1) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'pusha' instruction must not have arguments.");
        }

        emitOpcode(PUSH_ALL);
    }

    private void assemblePop(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'pop' instruction requires exactly two tokens: " + 
                    "\"pop regi\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(POP);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
    }

    private void assemblePopAll(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 1) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'popa' instruction must not have arguments.");
        }

        emitOpcode(POP_ALL);
    }

    private void assembleLsp(String line) {
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The 'lsp' instruction must contain exactly two tokens: " +
                    "\"lsp regi\"");
        }

        emitOpcode(LSP);
        emitRegister(tokens[1]);
    }

    private void assembleWord(String line) {
        if (!pendingLabels.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The word declaration expression must not have labels.");
        }

        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'word' instruction requireis exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"word name value\"");
        }

        int datum;

        if (isHexInteger(tokens[2])) {
            datum = hexStringToInteger(tokens[2]);
        } else if (isInteger(tokens[2])) {
            datum = toInteger(tokens[2]);
        } else {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    "Cannot parse \"" + tokens[2] + "\" as a decimal or " + 
                    "hexadecimal integer.");
        }

        if (mapWordNameToWordValue.containsKey(tokens[1])) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "Word with name \"" + tokens[1] + "\" is already defined.");
        }

        if (mapStringNameToStringValue.containsKey(tokens[1])) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "There is already a string with name \"" + tokens[1] + 
                    "\"");
        }

        mapWordNameToWordValue.put(tokens[1], datum);
    }

    private void assembleString(String line) {
        if (!pendingLabels.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The string declaration expression must not have labels.");
        }

        int firstQuoteIndex = line.indexOf("\"");

        if (firstQuoteIndex == -1) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The string must be enclosed in double quotation marks: " +
                    "str name \"string content\"");
        }

        int lastQuoteIndex  = line.lastIndexOf("\"");

        if (firstQuoteIndex == lastQuoteIndex) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "The string declaration has only one double quote: " +
                    "requires exactly two.");
        }

        String str = line.substring(firstQuoteIndex + 1, lastQuoteIndex);
        String[] tokens = toTokens(line);

        if (tokens.length < 3) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() + 
                    "The 'str' instruction requires exactly three tokens: " +
                    "\"str name value\"");
        }

        if (mapStringNameToStringValue.containsKey(tokens[1])) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "String with name \"" + tokens[1] + 
                    "\" is alredy defined.");
        }

        if (mapWordNameToWordValue.containsKey(tokens[1])) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "There is already a word with name \"" + tokens[1] + "\"");
        }

        str = str.replace("\\n", "\n");
        mapStringNameToStringValue.put(tokens[1], str);
    }

    private boolean isInteger(String token) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(token);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isHexInteger(String token) {
        if (token.length() < 3 
                || (!token.startsWith("0X") && !token.startsWith("0x"))) {
            return false;
        }

        String body = token.substring(2).toLowerCase();

        try {
            Long.parseLong(body, 16);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private int hexStringToInteger(String token) {
        if (!isHexInteger(token)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input token is not a hexadecimal number.");
        }

        return (int) Long.parseLong(token.substring(2).toLowerCase(), 16); 
    }

    private int toInteger(String token) {
        return Integer.parseInt(token);
    }

    private String[] toTokens(String line) {
        return line.split("\\s+");
    }

    private String[] handleLabel(String line) {
        int colonIndex = line.indexOf(":");

        if (colonIndex == -1) {
            return new String[]{ line };
        }

        if (line.indexOf(":", colonIndex + 1) != -1) {
            throw new AssemblyException(
                    errorHeader() +
                    "Only one label allowed per line. The input line is \"" +
                    line + "\".");
        }

        String label = line.substring(0, colonIndex).trim();
        String actualLine = line.substring(colonIndex + 1,
                                           line.length()).trim();

        this.mapLabelToAddress.put(label, machineCode.size());

        return new String[] { 
            label,
            actualLine
        };
    }

    private byte[] convertMachineCodeToByteArray() {
        byte[] code = new byte[machineCode.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; ++i) {
            code[i] = machineCode.get(i);
        }

        return code;
    }

    private String errorHeader() {
        return "ERROR in file \"" + fileName + 
               "\" at line " + lineNumber + ": ";
    }
}
```

- All the files are [here](https://github.com/coderodde/jToyAssembler).
- A small pack for demonstration is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/biwjcj1uk5rlnd4/toystuff.zip?dl=0)).
- The virtual machine is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/ToyVM)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Make your code more data driven

For any given instruction, the relevant pieces are spread over quite a bit of code.  A better approach might be to have something like an `Instruction` class that would contain the instruction string, the encoded hex value, the length and the number and type of arguments.

### Make error reporting more consistent

One of the problems with repeating very similar code multiple times is that small errors can creep in and be overlooked in the volume of code.  For example, the word "instruction" is misspelled for the `jmp` instruction error code, but not for the `jb` or other instructions, even though their error strings are nearly identical.

### Separate tokenizing from parsing

Classical assembler or compiler construction separates tokenizing from parsing.  The tokenizer (also called a "lexer" by some) creates a series of tokens, identified by type and value, to the parser.  This allows for more complex constructs, such as an "expression" to be parsed without having to also clutter the code with the parts that determine whether something is a number or an instruction mnemonic or a reference to a register.  Doing so will make it easier to modify and maintain both parts.

### Use existing string handling

The `emitRegister` uses a switch to enumerate each register and emit the corresponding value.  One could also do something like this instead:

```
String [] regNames= { "reg1", "reg2", "reg3", "reg4" };
int regnum = Arrays.binarySearch(regNames, registerToken);
if (regnum >= 0) {
    machineCode.add(regnum);
} else {
    throw ...
}
```

Now it's trivial to add "reg5" for example, just by listing its name.

### Create functions for common operations

There are several places in which an `int` is turned into little-endian format.  The code would be more clear and compact if that operation were implemented as a function instead.

### Be careful of what you accept

Right now, the assembler will happily accept lines like these:

```
jmp:    jmp jmp
reg3:   ja reg3
```

It's possible that this is intentional, but I'm not convinced it's good design.  In any case, this is almost certainly not intended:

```
0004:   jb 0004
```

It creates a label `0004` which cannot be used, and then assembles a `jb 0004` instruction.

### Consider using real compiler tools

You might want to look into using `flex` and `bison` (or `JFlex` and `BYACC` if you want to continue using Java for this).  They take a little bit of time to learn, but are well worth it.  Your entire program, for instance could be done quite simply in C using `flex` and `bison`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of code that is mostly copy-and-paste.  For each instruction, there's a opcode constant (e.g. `public static final byte ADD = 0x01;`), a map entry (e.g. `mapOpcodeToAssembler.put("add",   this::assembleAdd    );`) and a handler (the `assembleAdd()` method).

There is therefore an enormous opportunity to generalize.  Each instruction consists of an opcode, and may have zero to two arguments, which may be immediate values, registers, or addresses.  You could use an Enum, or you could have all the instructions defined in a configuration file.